# NPM error message appearing every time I start the terminal - Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, nvm

how are you?

So, every time I start up my terminal on my MacBook (OSX 10.15.4), I get the following message:

```
 /Users/anarenault/.nvm/v0.10.48/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
          ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.48 --silent` to unset it.
```

I already tried to uninstall and then install the latest version of Node.js and NVM, but the problem still. I also updated de zsh terminal shell (this is the shell I use). I really don't know what else I can do. I'm really lost here. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried the suggested fix?

`nvm use --delete-prefix v0.10.48 --silent`

I am only asking this because it's not mentioned anywhere if you have already tried this, and it could be a helpful tip.
Also make sure to try and run it using `sudo`, as I myself had some issues with Node.js in the past related to administrator privileges, even though I was logged in using my administrator account in my Linux laptop.

Comment: Hi here I seem to now have this issue andthe problem is that the reminal window opens with these errors and I can't type anything, so I can't try to run the nvm command

Comment: Hi @Kibi, can you try opening another new terminal window and running it there maybe?

Comment: Hi @Pedro , sorry, this was a while back in another company - I think in the end I just completely deleted the Node installation and started again